# How to invoke a function in another ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift4.2

How can I invoke a function/method in another firstViewController swift file while the control/state is in secondViewController. 
In Second ViewController when a button is pressed the secondViewController should invoke a function in firstViewController and transfer the control/state to thirdViewController to which it was pushed from secondViewController.

```
secondViewController Button Action
@IBAction func EnterGallery(_ sender: Any){
// Want to invoke EnterGallery function in firstViewController and dismiss from secondViewController
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}

firstViewController pushViewController function
func EnterGallery() {
let dest = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
"GalleryViewController") as! GalleryViewController // thirdViewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dest, animated: true)
 }
```

Please Note: I am not passing any Data from secondViewController to firstViewController. I just want my firstViewController to push to thirdViewController while I just dismiss from secondViewController which was presented from firstViewController with the present function. 
Once I dismiss from secondViewController I want my screen to go directly to thirdViewController.

Basically I just want to invoke a function in another ViewController without any data passing from initial ViewController. So I cannot use Protocols and Delegates or Notifications and Observers. How should I approach this?
There are many other cases where I need to use this similar functionality. So I am not sure how to exactly perform this. 
As I am new to Swift, any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use closures for this ... in my opinion best fit for this type of tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your viewController should know about other viewControllers and should be able to interact with them.

Here is a good [article](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/) about passing data between viewControllers (or just interacting between viewControllers - as you like)

The most common practice is delegation pattern. In two words about delegation:

Create a delegate protocol:

```
protocol MyDelegate {
    func doSmth()
}
```

Add delegate property to `viewController` that will trigger something in `anotherViewController`:

```
var delegate: MyDelegate?
```

`anotherViewController` should conform `MyDelegate` protocol:

```
class anotherViewController: MyDelegate {
    func doSmth() {
        print("I am doing something")
    }
}
```

And then assign your class that is conformed to `MyDelegate` protocol into this property

```
viewController.delegate = anotherViewController
```

Thats it! Now you can trigger delegate method inside `viewController`

```
delegate.doSmth()
```

Comment: This method is not working for me. Could you please check once and send me the working code.?

Answer (score 0):

Google delegate pattern for this. YT: https://youtu.be/DBWu6TnhLeY
Hopefully this helps you out. By the way delegate pattern works even if you don’t want to pass data in between.